# VS Code Java System Output Encoding

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, encoding

I have a problem with encoding of Java System Output occurring only in **Visual Studio Code**.

My program is very simple:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy");
    }
}
```

but the output looks like this:

`Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy�ábelské ódy�dy`

My file has the **UTF-8** encoding and it's being compiled with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` flag. I am using the official **Java Extension Pack by Microsoft** in **Visual Studio Code**.

Answer (score 0):

as you had installed "Java Extension Pack", and mentioned "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", so, you are debug through "Debugger for Java" extension. that's caused the fails of I want to recurrence your problem.

I tried to edit the encoding of terminal, through task.json, or in the settings.json adds "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/K", "chcp 65001"], but both of them not works.

that's of course, as the "Debugger for Java" extension will open a new terminal to execute the commands, as the settings above will not take a infulence on that terminal.

so, I can recurrence your problem this time, as I open the "launcher.bat" file, which shows in the commands, and change the code -> "chcp.com 65001 > NUL" in it. any other number of chcp.com will caused your problem.

so, maybe, this can provide some inspirations to you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply! In my "launcher.bat" file I already have the number set to 65001, anyway it still doesn't work properly.

Comment: In your java process console, after running your code, could you type chcp to confirm your console's encoding type?
and could you leave the vscode, just in the cmd to run this class? I mean javac, then java, to confirm wheather it works? and try to chcp 65001, to confirm it works?
you know, it's only three possibilities, your file's encode, the terminal encode, your computer's encode problem, I can't think out any other conditions.

Comment: After running my code the console prints this:
C:\Users\username\program> C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.25.1\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\027e691179a119970fc375cc4fc26f8f\redhat.java\jdt_ws\hellow_a2fe7d28\bin Main

If I compile my program classicaly with javac and java the output in Windows CMD has correct encoding.

Comment: sorry, I am weekend, could you please open a new cmd and type in chcp, check it is 65001 or not, and you'd better turn your PC encoding to UTF-8. as I had meet the problem as you descriped, as last time I test everything is ok, so, I makes some investigate.

Answer (score 0):

vscode was different from your original 'javac,java' commands, as vscode depends on extensions to execute those commands.

through "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" extension compile '.java' file to '.class', it customized add '-encoding utf8' args.

through "Debugger for Java" extension to change the terminal 'chcp' to '65001', and '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' to make sure the JVM start with encoding 'utf8'.

you can achieve the same effects through add enviroments variable:
"JDK_JAVAC_OPTIONS":"-encoding utf8", 
"JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS":"-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8",
and 'chcp 65001' to temporary change the terminal encoding.

it's very complex and strange, as I can not sure what's the 'java', 'javac' default encoding, I had tried a lot but still confusing, as I googled a lot, but cann't get the enough informations. but everythings are included in those three variables, I hope this can provide you some useful informations, I am too tired. sorry...

Answer (score 0):

for code runner extention,just add this code to user setting json:

```
"code-runner.executorMap":{"java": "cd $dir && javac -encoding utf-8 $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",},
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue. My environment is a little bit complicated.
I use both of 'Code-Runner' and 'Java-extenstion Pack.' That seems to make it harder for me to resolve the issue.

After several trying, I found out below things.

1. When I use run icon (in upper-right side), 'code-runner' compine and run my code in "OUTPUT", which shows broken Korean characters.
2. When I use "Run > Debugging" or "Run > Run Without Debugging", 'Java extension Pack' compile and run my code in "TERMINAL", which shows Korean characters properly.

Below is my final settings.

A. settings.json in workspace

- Insert **-encoding utf-8** in 'code-runner.executoMap'

```
....
"code-runner.executorMap": {
  "javascript": "node",
  "java": "cd $dir && javac -encoding utf-8 $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
.....
  "sml": "cd $dir && sml $fileName"
}
```

B. settings.json in User

- Add `"java.jdt.ls.vmargs": "-Dfile.encoding=utf-8"`
- Add `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true`

After setting, code-runner prints Korean characters well in "TERMINAL"(not "OUTPUT"), and 'java extension pack' also does.